# BackboneJS - add class to <a href> of <li> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I want to add an `.active`-class to the specific menuItem which has been clicked, so in my Backbone View I have:

```
initialize: function () {
    if(this.model.has('triggers') && this.model.get('triggers') == this.model.get('route')) {
            this.$el.addClass('active');
    } else {
            this.$el.removeClass('active');
            }   
}
```

This gives the the `<li>` the active class, but I want the `<a href>`-element to have the active class, so I tried:

```
this.$el.closest('a').addClass('active');
```

but apparently that does not work since i become the **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier **-error. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

Try [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
this.$el.find('a').addClass('active');
```

Comment: Note that you can shortcut this with `this.$('a')` (see http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar)

Comment: +1 This should do the trick: 'closest' traverses _up_ the DOM, that's the reason it was not working.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution, use backbone **EVENTS OBJECT** inside your view, because it a BACKBONE way.

```
var view = {
  //some code before 
  events: {
    "click a.YOUR_CLASS_TO_WATCH_CLICK_EVENT": "handler"
  },

  handler: function(e){
    var target = $(e.currentTarget);
    target.addClass("active");
    return false;
  }
  //some code after
}
```

So add to your `<a class="SOME_CLASS">` some className and change YOUR_CLASS_TO_WATCH_CLICK_EVENT to this className.